# Commenting code in Notepad++

Tags: comments, notepad++

I'm using *Notepad++* as an editor to write programs in Python. It might sound daft but I looked around in the editor and could not find any means (not the manual way but something like in Emacs) to do a block comment in my code.

Since so many language settings are supported in *Notepad++*, I'm curious to find a way to block comment code.

Comment: Both CTRL-K and CTRL-Q can be seen in the Edit menu of Notepad++

Comment: "comment sections of my code"?  In Python?  The "#" key is missing?  Clearly, you're not talking about Python comments using "#" or docstrings.  What are you talking about?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to block comment my code written in Python or in fact any other language, in Notepad++ editor. May be that was not quite clear from my question. But Niels's and other answers helped.

Comment: Are you talking about applying comments to all lines of a block of code?  Please update the question -- don't comment on your own question when you can fix the question.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to comment out the current line of code? Ctrl-K and Ctrl-Q both need selected characters to work.

Comment: @ReadySquid - Notepad++ version 6.6.8 does not require any selection for Ctrl-K or Ctrl-Q to work (Introduced sometime in the last 5 years)

Comment: @toto, It's not shown. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> Block comment/uncomment.

See [Keyboard And Mouse Shortcuts - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts).

Comment: CTRL+Q is line comment, for block comment the shortcut is CTRL+SHIFT+Q

Comment: @machineaddict, [What's the opposite](http://superuser.com/questions/790353/fastest-way-to-comment-out-multiple-lines-in-notepad/916881#comment1267743_790354) of that?

Comment: I've seen you are searching for this keyboard shortcut in multiple posts on SE websites. I don't know the shortcut. I only use Ctrl-Q combinations for comments.

Comment: Note that in order for it to work, you **MUST** specify the (programming) Language for the code. Also, if you copypaste a piece of code to a new file without specifying the language manually - or - it contains a mix of languages (eg. inline SQL in Python code), the block comment/uncomment *will not work*.

Comment: I laughed at first because i entered ctrl+w (thinking i actually hit ctrl+q(uit) like the answer proposed). but yeah, ctrl+q will actually comment multiple lines in notepad++ whereas netbeans uses ctrl + shift + w to comment multiple lines.

Comment: For comment press Ctrl+Q or Ctrl + Shift + Q or Ctrl+K.
For uncomment press Ctrl+Shift+K.

Comment: The link is dead, and I didn't find an appropriate reference in the [user manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/ "Editing | Notepad++ User Manual"). For a compact overview, see for example [Notepad++ Cheat Sheet - Notepad++_Cheat_Sheet.pdf](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Notepad++_Cheat_Sheet.pdf).

Answer (score 27):

Try the following shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Answer (score 25):

This link was exactly what I was searching for .

Let me summarize the answers for others' benefit (**for python and notepad++**)

1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on multiple lines (i.e. selected region) allows you to ***block comment***.

Also note that pressing the combination multiple times allows you to add multiple "#"s (sometimes I use that while testing to differentiate from other comments)

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (on the commented region) allows you to perform ***block uncomment***

3) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on an uncommented selected region ***does not comment it***

4)  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> allows you to **block comment/uncomment** in a ***toggled mode*** (meaning, you cannot add multiple '#'s like in 1) )

Hope this helps another wandering soul.

*Question - how would you develop a hack of keyboard combinations to comment/uncomment if there were no shortcuts? Just curious. I've no clue hence asking.*

Comment: `Hope this helps another wandering soul.` It does.

Answer (score 14):

Yes in **Notepad++** you can do that!

Some hotkeys regarding comments:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> Toggle block comment
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> Block comment
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>    Block uncomment
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>    Stream comment

Source: [shortcutworld.com](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Notepad-plus-plus_5.9.html) from the **Comment / uncomment** section.

On the link you will find many other useful shortcuts too.

Comment: Upvoted as this is the first answer to correctly mention that Ctrl+Shift+Q turns the whole selection into ONE comment instead of commenting each line separately.

Comment: @walen What difference do you mean? For me, Ctrl+Shift+Q and Ctrl+K have the same effect. What does "stream comment" mean?

Comment: @root Comment using one `/*` at the beggining of the block and one `*/` at the end of it, instead of one `//` on each line which is what Ctrl+K does (for me and user3898160 at least).

Comment: @walen Got it, thanks. Depending on the programming language, Ctrl+Shift+Q and Ctrl+K may or may not have the same effect.

Answer (score 9):

for .sql files <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does not work.

to insert comments in .sql files in Notepad++  try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

(there is no shortcut to uncomment the code block though. I have tried that on v5.8.2 )

Comment: To Get Ctrl-K and Ctrl-Q working for SQL you need to edit the langs.xml file in the Notepad++ directory. (With Admin rights, and with notepad++ closed).  Add commentLine="--" to the language settings for SQL.

Comment: From  [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html) - _From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax._ **So, see if you need to use "-- ", but Notepad++ will change the color either way**

Comment: @BillyNair, Wow, good catch! Notepad++'s invalid highlighting is going to cause some serious bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Use shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
You can customize in *Settings*

Answer (score 1):

In your n++ editor, you can go to 
***Setting*** > ***Shortcut mapper***
and find all shortcut information as well as you can edit them :)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways for block commenting:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

or

1. Select the block
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right click
3. Choose block comment.

Answer (score 1):

Without having selected a language type for your file there are no styles defined.  Comment and block comment are language specific style preferences.  If that's a PITA...

To select for multi-line editing you can use

`shift` + `alt` + `down arrow`

Answer (score 1):

To add a comment under any code on NOTEPAD++ first we have to save and define the programming or scripting file type. Like, save the file as xml, html etc. Once the file is saved in proper format you will be able to add a comment directly using the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just select the  desired line and  click  on `Ctrl` + `Q`
Ps: I am  using  Notepad++