# How to use multi-line (Block) comment in sikuli IDE?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide

I am using sikuli IDE for automation. In sikuli IDE, we can put single line comment 
as '#'.

But I couldn't find any way to put multi-line(block) comment in sikuli IDE. I am referring sikuli official documentation site http://doc.sikuli.org.

I have tried
/*

*/

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently commenting whole blocks is not available in Sikuli IDE, but there is an open request for such functionality in Sikuli 1.1.0. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/585342) is the source.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Sikuli documentation site](http://doc.sikuli.org) section 'How to use this document', one can use any syntax of the Python language in Sikuli script.

Hence, the link for [Python's multi-line comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696966/1120530) may help.

```
'''
This is a multiline
comment.
'''
```

Comment: Python syntax for multiline (block) comment is /* */ . I have tried this. It does not work.

Comment: Use triple quoted string as:  
'''  
you could do  
something like this  
as a multi-line comment'''

Comment: I also have tried '''  ''' (triple quotes), even this also didn't work.

Comment: triple quotes works in the ide for me in sikuli 1.0.1

Comment: @Dale Updated the link