# python, x = """"""; lexed as triple quotes or 3 pairs of quotes

Tags: python

In python you can say this:

```
x = """""" # x = ''
```

Does the Python lexer see this as two triple quotes with nothing inside? I.e. along the lines of `x = """ """` (with no space)?

This was my immediate thought. However, this is possible in python:

```
>>> "4" "5"
'45'
>>> # and
>>> "4""5"
'45'
```

So I can see that `x = """"""` might also be lexed along the lines of `x = "" "" ""` (with no spaces).
I'm just wondering, is `""""""` lexed as two triple quotes or three pairs of normal quotes? Or something else entirely? Thanks!

EDIT: Obviously, it doesn't matter as a programmer in Python. However, the Python interpreter definitely must pick one of these and I'm wondering which.

Comment: rval?  are you confused, python does not have rvalues.

Comment: @IfLoop Fixed that, sorry, thought I was using the right terminology.

Comment: i wonder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924/multiline-comments-in-python is what you looking for

Comment: @Selva, nope I don't see how that's relevant. This has nothing to do with comments.

Comment: Does it matter? Either way you get the empty string.

Comment: There would be no difference between the two interpretations - three empty strings is still an empty string `"" * 3 == """""" == "" "" "" == ""`. For any non-empty example it is clear to see which is being used, although they're still equal: `"f""o""o" == """foo""" == "foo"`.

Comment: @Wooble, maybe it doesn't. But I'm positive Python interprets this deterministically... and I'm just wondering how

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it doesn't matter that there is no difference. The Python interpreter definitely picks one, and I'm wondering which it picks.

Comment: The explanation of triple quotes is not far from the start of the tutorial: [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). More details can be found in the [Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Comment: The compiler picks one. The bytecode generated for `""""""` and `"" "" ""` both contains `LOAD_CONST               1 ('')`; by the time it's interpreted they're identical.

Comment: @phileaton why doesn't it matter? It wouldn't make any difference if the *interpreter* did the same thing every time, picked one randomly or selected based on the phase of the moon. This is an *implementation detail* and makes no difference to the outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell by using the [tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html):

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from tokenize import generate_tokens as gt
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> code = 'x=""""""'
>>> codeio = StringIO(code)
>>> tokens = list(gt(codeio.readline))
>>> pp(tokens)
[(1, 'x', (1, 0), (1, 1), 'x=""""""'),
 (51, '=', (1, 1), (1, 2), 'x=""""""'),
 (3, '""""""', (1, 2), (1, 8), 'x=""""""'),
 (0, '', (2, 0), (2, 0), '')]
```

The first token is 'x'. the second is '=' and the third is '""""""'. There are not three '""' tokens.

P.S. for comparison:

```
>>> othercode='y="led" "zeppelin"'
>>> othercodeio = StringIO(othercode)
>>> othertokens = list(gt(othercodeio.readline))
>>> pp(othertokens)
[(1, 'y', (1, 0), (1, 1), 'y="led" "zeppelin"'),
 (51, '=', (1, 1), (1, 2), 'y="led" "zeppelin"'),
 (3, '"led"', (1, 2), (1, 7), 'y="led" "zeppelin"'),
 (3, '"zeppelin"', (1, 8), (1, 18), 'y="led" "zeppelin"'),
 (0, '', (2, 0), (2, 0), '')]
```

Answer (score 1):

its lexically a single string.  triple quoted strings are the only form that can span multiple lines (unlike some other languages, which allow all strings, or no strings to span lines).

this particular syntax was probably selected since it makes syntax highlighting simple, flag matched pairs of quotes.  Although this can still erroneously highlight invalid python (single quoted strings that span lines), it's good enough for text editors, usually.

the parser, when it reads a quote, checks for two more of the same type of quote, and if it finds them, terminates the string only on three more consecutive quotes.  Otherwise it terminates the string on the next quote, unless there's a newline first, in which case it produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is identified as a pair of triple quotes only.

Check this

```
>>> id("""""")
140579203310856

>>> id("")
140579203310856

>>> id("" "" "")
140579203310856
```

which basically means, the pair of triple quotes are identified the same as a normal quote.

Also, if you do an id of two double quotes, as follows

```
>>> id("""")
....
```

it won't terminate since the lexer is now treating it as a docstring and is expecting the string to terminate validly.

Comment: "and is expecting another two quotes for the string to terminate validly".. Nope, it's expecting 3 consecutive quotes for the string to terminate validly.  The 3 quotes to end the string have to all come at once, you can't pay by instalments.

Comment: @user9876 Ok, we are both wrong here. I just tried. 3 quotes won't work either, since there was a 4th quote character initially which was entered unescaped. Trying to figure this out now.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything.  Did you try `id("" "" "")`?

Comment: @user9876 Turns out, it is 4 quotes. `id("""")""""` evaluates with error `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: So is `"" "" ""` also "identified as a pair of triple quotes"? :-) By the time you get to the level of a Python object (after lexing, parsing to concrete syntax tree, conversion to abstract syntax tree, compilation to bytecode, interpretation of that bytecode), the distinction between `"" "" ""`, `""` and `""""""` is long gone.  You can't say anything about how the *tokenizer* treats `""""""` from looking at ids of generated Python objects!

Comment: @MarkDickinson Got your point :) Initially when I read the question, I thought OP was asking whether they are the same or not, and answered accordingly. I think the question has been suitably edited.

Answer (score -1):

if you have no text, it is the same.
try the following:

```
>>> """abc"""
'abc'
>>> "a""b""c"
'abc'
>>> "a""b""c" == """abc"""
True
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `ast` module to see the syntax tree python uses for this. e.g:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> source = '""""""""'
>>> node = ast.parse(source, mode='eval')
>>> ast.dump(node)
"Expression(body=Str(s=''))"
```

As you can see, it's an empty string.