# How can I comment #define_line

Tags: python, comments

I know that in regular lines it can do this

```
#print "Comment Line."
```

and the whole line is a comment

But I want to comment a "define line" in Python.
For example

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I thought it will "comment" the whole line, so the interpreter will ignore it, but it's not what happen. The interpreter refer to it as"regular define

In C if I remember it right it's simple, and it's something like this

```
//#define Hello Holly
```

But how can I do that in Python?

Comment: I haven't tested, but what happens if you add an extra `#` to the beginning of the line?

Comment: I tried it, but the line wasn't been ignored, nothing really happend

Comment: Just in case there are any "duplicate" flags inbound...  This is _not_  a duplicate of "[Multiline comments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924)", because this question is (unwittingly) about behavior _specific to [`coding` comments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)_ when they appear on the first or second line of a `.py` file, and not to any other comments.  Matt. St's question about a multi-line comment syntax is really an attempt to work around this one special comment syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "define line" in Python. The `coding` thing you show is *already* a comment, but it's a comment with [special interpretation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

If you want to prevent a `coding` comment from taking effect without removing it, move it down to the third line of the file or lower by inserting blank lines or more comments above it.

Comment: thanks, it does help. though I have a new question, does moving lines with "comment with special interpretation" to the third line make them to be ignored? or it's just `coding` ?

Comment: @Matt.St: This is specific to Python's handling of `coding` comments. I don't know of any other comments that Python treats specially, but there are comments like shebang lines that get interpreted by other systems and follow different rules.

Answer (score -1):

I think `/*` and `*/` might be block-all comments, but if not, docstrings (triple quotes) are.

Comment: in Python, multi-line comments are the triple quotes. But I don't know if that would solve the OP's question.

Comment: Docstrings are different form multi line comments.

Comment: `/* ... */` style comments are available in C, C++, Java, and some other languages, but _not_ Python.