# python multiline comment indent

Tags: python, pep8

I have a Django project, and in some places we have multiline comments indented as follows:

```
field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)  # 0-initial_email_sent
                                                   # 1-second_email_sent
                                                   # 2-third_email_sent
```

This clearly violates PEP, but, in my opinion, helps with readability. Of course, I could put comments like this:

```
# 0-initial_email_sent
# 1-second_email_sent
# 2-third_email_sent
field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

, but I would much rather prefer the first one.

Is there any way to indent comments as such without violating PEP 8?

Comment: Don't know if this is "canonical", but the [Python Style guide (PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) distinguishes between block comments and in-line comments. There is no such thing as in-line block comments.

Comment: If your `field` were named `number_of_emails_sent`, and you used the appropriate integer value, then you wouldn't need the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magic numbers are evil, so the best documentation here is to use named (pseudo) constants:

```
INITIAL_EMAIL_SENT = 0
SECOND_EMAIL_SENT = 1
THIRD_EMAIL_SENT = 2
field = models.IntegerField(default=INITIAL_EMAIL_SENT, null=True)
```

As a general rule, the less you have to comment the better (clear code needs no or very very few comments).

For a more general answer about where to place comments, specially multiline ones:

1. having the comments before the commented item is what most python users expect so for the majority of is it *is* "more readable"
2. it also makes code editing easier (you don't have comments mixed with code, you don't have to maintain comments indentation etc).

If it's your own personal project and you don't plan on sharing it or having anyone else working on it you are (hopefully) free to use any coding style / convention, pep08 is no religion, but if someone else ever have to work on your code he will certainly hate you for commenting this way.

Comment: He is talking about comment. Why introducing constants ? I am also a naive in python. Just asking question. I didn't understand your point here ?

Comment: @AdilMalik: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus that's what i am asking Bruno to explain here. Still not sure why he thinks constants are better than triple-quote strings

Comment: I fully agree that named constants are much better. However the question itself isn't about magic numbers, but about multiline comments. Probably my example is just bad, then.

Comment: @AdilMalik cf my added explanations.

Comment: @НазарТопольський I understand the question was not about magic numbers but my point was that clear code needs way less comments ;)

Comment: Now that you have actually touched the issue, I will accept this answer, because I do agree that such commenting style smells kinda bad.

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924/multiline-comments-in-python)
You could also use multi-line comments like this.

```
"""
This is how yo can use Python Multi-line Comments
Line two is here.
Line three is here.
"""
```

Comment: [You just violated PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes).

Comment: @Mitch  is it correct now ? Thanks i never knew that :)

Comment: This is not a multi-line comment, it's a (triple-quoted) string.

Comment: Same question was asked here. and they said its a multiline comment. @brunodesthuilliers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924/multiline-comments-in-python

Comment: Multiline strings can be used as comments in that they can be used to describe something and they do not generate bytecode, however, they are not. For instance, if you place it just after function declaration, it will be treated as docstrings, they aren't highlighted as comments by IDEs I know about and, frankly, seem just odd.

Comment: @AdilMalik They are wrong. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100436/172176

Comment: @aya I would certainly upvote your comment if I could. Not only is the answer wrong, but also (in a way) dangerous, since it can lead to errors.