# How to comment mass block of plpythonu function in PgAdmin?

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a function in `PgAdmin` written in `plpythonu`.

I want to change 38 rows into comment.
If this would be a plpgsql function I would mark the code and click `CTRL+K` which gives  `--` in the `start` of all the rows.

How can I do that for `plpythonu`? It should be `#`

Comment: Use [multiline comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7696924/593144) instead.

Comment: @Abelisto while it works in Python.. it doesn't work in plpythonu. It causes  error ERROR: could not compile PL/Python function

Comment: It works fine for me. Make sure that the `'''` or `"""` is on the same position as an surrounding code.

Comment: @Abelisto can you give an example for the function you compile successfully?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function pfoo() returns int stable language plpythonu as $$
  r = 1
  """
  r = 2
  r = 3
  """
  return r
$$;
```