# Section Header Comments in Python

Tags: python, comments

I've searched on Google and could not find any information on recommended ways to highlight sections of code with comments.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
###########################################################
# This section is clearly labeled using comments so you can 
# instantly identify its purpose within this file.
###########################################################
```

I see this kind of thing a lot in `php` for example.

Is there a convention for this kind of thing in python? If not, is there a good reason to avoid it?

If this is generally done using multi-line comments, could someone please provide an example of how it's done in this "headline" style?

EDIT: I know about multi-line comments. But generally I associate these with a single function rather than a section of code. So more specifically I'm thinking something like this for a small game in a single file:

```
###################################################
#              CONFIGURATION   
##################################################

configuration code...

###################################################
#              HELPER FUNCTIONS
#################################################   

helper functions.....

###################################################
#                 GRAPHICS HANDLING
#######################################################

graphics handling....
```

Comment: Take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924/way-to-create-multiline-comments-in-python

Comment: Do you mean highlight the code in comments in IDE?

Comment: In Spyder, you can use `# %% Section Header` to mark a collapsible section of code. I have no idea if that's just in Spyder or a more widespread convention.

Answer (score 3):

```
##############
# Game Setup #
##############

code...

##################
# Function Setup #
##################

code...

################
# Screen Setup #
################

code...
```

That's the kind of thing I meant. Found some good examples in https://github.com/lordmauve/pgzero