# How to uncomment multiple lines of a Cmake file in notepad++?

Tags: cmake, compilation, notepad++, editor

My cmake file looks like this. I want to uncomment the lines 1 through 100 with a single shortcut

```
#line1
#line2
#line3
.
.
.
#line100

build(a_library
USING
b
c)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commenting code in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022261/commenting-code-in-notepad) Commenting and un-commenting CMake code is no different from other languages in Notepad++. Just use the **CTRL + SHIFT + K** keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(FALSE) # fake a block comment

endif()
```

Note that this works well for commenting out a block of valid CMake code, it doesn't allow you write plain text within the `if` block

As of CMake 3.0 there is a special syntax for block comments which start with `#[[` and ends with `]]` at the end of block comment.

Comment: This is working for me, what I did was for commenting `if(FALSE) # fake a block comment

endif()`. And for uncomment `if(TRUE) # fake a block comment

endif()`